# Convert columns values into multiple records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

In SQL Server 2008, I have a table with following columns and data

```
Date    Name    Colors  Color1  Color2  Color3
Nov01   John    Red
Nov02   Mike    Green   Blue    Grey
Nov03   Melissa Yellow  Orange
Nov10   Rita    Pink    Red
```

I want to make new table or change above table with data shown as

```
Date    Name    Colors
Nov01   John    Red
Nov02   Mike    Green
Nov02   Mike    Blue
Nov02   Mike    Grey
Nov03   Melissa Yellow
Nov03   Melissa Orange
Nov10   Rita    Pink
Nov10   Rita    Red
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the primary key?

Comment: Hello, I have similar question for opposite situation. I would appreciate if you can respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or using [PIVOT & UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

```
SELECT  t.Date,
        unpvt.Name,
        unpvt.Color
FROM 
   (SELECT  Name, Colors, Color1, Color2, Color3
   FROM dbo.MYTABLE) p
UNPIVOT
   (Color FOR [Date] IN 
      (Colors, Color1, Color2, Color3)
)AS unpvt
Join dbo.MYTABLE t on t.[Name] = unpvt.[Name]
Where unpvt.Color != ''
```

Comment: Hello, I have similar question for opposite situation. I would appreciate if you can respond
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256441/convert-multiple-records-into-once-column

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly my most elegant answer but i think it will still work

```
Select Date, Name, Colors as Colors
Where Colors is not null
Union All
Select Date, Name, Color1 as Colors
Where Color1 is not null
Union All
Select Date, Name, Color2 as Colors
Where Color2 is not null
Union All
Select Date, Name, Color3 as Colors
Where Color3 is not null
```

Comment: + 1: Was a few seconds away from having the same answer typed out.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in UNPIVOT

```
SELECT [Date], [Name], [Colors]
FROM 
   (SELECT [Date], [Name], [Color1], [Color2], [Color3]
   FROM myColors) p
UNPIVOT
   ([Colors] FOR x IN 
      ([Color1], [Color2], [Color3])
) AS unpvt;
```