# Convert multiple records into one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

In SQL  2008, I have below table and need to convert into following table creating one record for each

```
Date    Name    Colors
Nov01   John    Red
Nov02   Mike    Green
Nov02   Mike    Blue
Nov02   Mike    Grey
Nov03   Melissa Yellow
Nov03   Melissa Orange
Nov10   Rita    Pink
Nov10   Rita    Red
```

Converted

```
Date    Name    Red Green   Blue    Grey    Yellow  Orange
Nov01   John    Red
Nov02   Mike        Green   Blue    Grey
Nov03   Melissa                 Yellow  Orange
Nov10   Rita    Red                     Pink
```

See below pic, as I do not know how to format table here

[image]

Many thanks.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @OP, Please search SO before posting a question. A quick search revealed that this has been answered **MANY** times.

Comment: Thanks Marc_s and Brad. I should have searched with Pivot search word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:

[How to pivot rows into columns (custom pivoting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120835/how-to-pivot-rows-into-columns-custom-pivoting)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want a Dynamic Pivot.

Add this Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[pivotsp]
  @query    AS NVARCHAR(MAX),                   -- The query, can also be the name of a table/view.
  @on_rows  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),                   -- The columns that will be regular rows.
  @on_cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),                   -- The columns that are to be pivoted.
  @agg_func AS NVARCHAR(257) = N'SUM',          -- Aggregate function.
  @agg_col  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),                   -- Column to aggregate.
  @output   AS NVARCHAR(257) = N'',             -- Table for results
  @debug    AS bit = 0                          -- 1 for debugging
AS

-- Example usage:
--    exec pivotsp
--          'select * from vsaleshistory',
--          'market,marketid,family,familyid,Forecaster,Forecasterid,product,productid',
--          'month',
--          'sum',
--          'ku',
--          '##sales'

-- Input validation
IF @query IS NULL OR @on_rows IS NULL OR @on_cols IS NULL
   OR @agg_func IS NULL OR @agg_col IS NULL
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('Invalid input parameters.', 16, 1);
  RETURN;
END

-- Additional input validation goes here (SQL Injection attempts, etc.)

BEGIN TRY
  DECLARE
    @sql     AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @cols    AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @newline AS NVARCHAR(2);

  SET @newline = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

  -- If input is a valid table or view
  -- construct a SELECT statement against it
  IF COALESCE(OBJECT_ID(@query, N'U'),
              OBJECT_ID(@query, N'V')) IS NOT NULL
    SET @query = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @query;

  -- Make the query a derived table
  SET @query = N'(' + @query + N') AS Query';

  -- Handle * input in @agg_col
  IF @agg_col = N'*'
    SET @agg_col = N'1';

  -- Construct column list
  SET @sql =
      N'SET @result = '                                    + @newline +
      N'  STUFF('                                          + @newline +
      N'    (SELECT N'','' +  quotename( '
                   + 'CAST(pivot_col AS sysname)' +
                   + ')  AS [text()]'                          + @newline +
      N'     FROM (SELECT DISTINCT('
                   + @on_cols + N') AS pivot_col'              + @newline +
      N'           FROM' + @query + N') AS DistinctCols'   + @newline +
      N'     ORDER BY pivot_col'                           + @newline +
      N'     FOR XML PATH(''''))'                          + @newline +
      N'    ,1, 1, N'''');'

  IF @debug = 1
     PRINT @sql

  EXEC sp_executesql
    @stmt   = @sql,
    @params = N'@result AS NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT',
    @result = @cols OUTPUT;

  IF @debug = 1
     PRINT @cols

  -- Create the PIVOT query
  IF @output = N''
      begin
        SET @sql =
            N'SELECT *'                                          + @newline +
            N'FROM (SELECT '
                          + @on_rows
                          + N', ' + @on_cols + N' AS pivot_col'
                          + N', ' + @agg_col + N' AS agg_col'        + @newline +
            N'      FROM ' + @query + N')' +
                          + N' AS PivotInput'                        + @newline +
            N'  PIVOT(' + @agg_func + N'(agg_col)'               + @newline +
            N'    FOR pivot_col IN(' + @cols + N')) AS PivotOutput;'
      end
  ELSE
      begin
        set @sql = 'IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.objects WHERE  ' +
            'name = ''' + @output + ''' AND type = N''U'') DROP TABLE tempdb.' + @output
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

        SET @sql =
            N'SELECT * INTO ' + @output                          + @newline +
            N'FROM (SELECT '
                          + @on_rows
                          + N', ' + @on_cols + N' AS pivot_col'
                          + N', ' + @agg_col + N' AS agg_col'        + @newline +
            N'      FROM ' + @query + N')' +
                          + N' AS PivotInput'                        + @newline +
            N'  PIVOT(' + @agg_func + N'(agg_col)'               + @newline +
            N'    FOR pivot_col IN(' + @cols + N')) AS PivotOutput;'
      end

    IF @debug = 1
       PRINT @sql

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  DECLARE
    @error_message  AS NVARCHAR(2047),
    @error_severity AS INT,
    @error_state    AS INT;

  SET @error_message  = ERROR_MESSAGE();
  SET @error_severity = ERROR_SEVERITY();
  SET @error_state    = ERROR_STATE();

  RAISERROR(@error_message, @error_severity, @error_state);

  RETURN;
END CATCH
```

and then

```
exec pivotsp 'select * from mytable',
  '[date],name',
  'colours',
  'min',
  '#temp'
select * from #temp
```

(The MIN is a bit of a hack, but it should produce what you want)